# List all repo from GitHub through terminal/CLI

Tags: github, github-cli

I want to understand that is there any way to ****list all the repo which are created on github** through cli/terminal.**

I have more than 500 repo in my GitHub account. Need to list all the repo through cli

if yes then what is the command to do this.

Comment: Maybe this: https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_list ?

Answer (score 2):

You can list all owner's repos by using the [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_list) with the command:

```
gh repo list [owner] [flags]
```

I ended up using:

```
gh repo list --source --json name --limit 200 <account_name>
```

Since I wanted all of them in one go, skipping forks.